# ClickOnce deployment requires Framework 4.5 required when 4.5.2 is installed

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, clickonce

I know that the similar questions has been asked, and I've read them, however I can't understand why it happens with Framework 4.5.2
I've make ClickOnce publish and it requires .net framework 4.5 when 4.5.2 is installed . I can run it in debug mode or build it without any problems. Can someone answer why it happens and how can I solve this issue?

My install log

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string} 
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.1.1 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 и x64)', phase   BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read string value '4.5.51209'
Setting value '4.5.51209 {string}' for property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion'
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\1049'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet45FullLangPack_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 и x64)':
Property: [DotNet45Full_TargetVersion] = 4.5.51209 {string}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' 
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion' and value '4.5.50709': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45LP_Full_x86_x64ru.exe'
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet45FullLangPack_TargetVersion' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '6.0.0': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45LP_Full_x86_x64ru.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 и x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
 EULA for components 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 и x64)' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\kdi\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD3A61.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\kdi\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD3A61.tmp\"
(02.03.2015 15:03:51) Downloading 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45LP_Full_x86_x64ru.exe' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=249114&clcid=0x419' to 'C:\Users\kdi\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD3A61.tmp\'
Download completed at 02.03.2015 15:03:51
Downloading failed with HRESULT=-2146697210
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx)
is a way I found out that 4.5.2 is installed

Comment: Are you saying it runs fine **manually** deployed in debug/release but `fails` when you `ClickOnce` deploy?  Are both machines the same?

Comment: Yes sir, It runs fine manually deployed in debug/release but when I start setup my ClickOnce published project it requres framework 4.5.

Comment: ,NET 4.5.2 doesn't require 4.5. 4.5.2 is a binary replacement of 4.5. If you have issues with your ClickOnce deployment, you should check the ClickOnce deployment settings. What exactly is the problem and when does it appear? Does the target machine have 4.5/4.5.2? Did you check the setup log? What prerequisites have you specified? Did you specify 4.5.2 as a prerequisite or 4.5?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, my target machine has framework 4.5.2. I've check my ClickOnce settings: target framework is 4.5. My problem appears when I begin to install my published application, it requires framework 4.5 when 4.5.2 is installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem has been solved. On my machine was installed framework 4.5.2 but it was english language oriented version. From [this place](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx) I found it out.This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5a4x27ek(v=vs.100).aspx) helped me either.
My application is russian language oriented, so I had to install framework 4.5.2 special for russian language. That's why I downloaded framework 4.5.2 for developers(multilanguage) and installed it. Everything works fine.
But as I understood it will install only languages used in system. For example framework for deutch language was not installed.

Hope it will help someone someday;)

Sincerely, Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Framework 4.5.1. In my case it has never asked me to install framework 4.5.
I think you have to first uninstall it then install again with full package. Be care full while installing. All the best :)

Which package you are installing? I mean to say that Visual Studio Professional or any other? Please install Visual Studio Professional. Hope this will help you.

> Operating System Support
>
> The Visual Studio bootstrapper is not supported on Windows Server 2008
>   Server Core or Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core, which provide a
>   low-maintenance server environment with limited functionality. For
>   example, the Server Core installation option only supports the .NET
>   Framework 3.5 Server Core profile, so Visual Studio features that
>   depend on the full .NET Framework cannot run.

for reference click on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1.aspx

Comment: Sir, I've tried it already. At first I installed framework 4.5.2 than I've removed it and install 4.5. It didn't solve my problem. Also I've tried to install 4.5.1 however it didn't help

Comment: I use Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. In additional I'd like to say that I have the same version from the same source installed on the other machine and everything runs ok, I've checked it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't remover and add framework versions, you will only hose your development machine. Problems with deployment mean either that the deployment package has problems or the target machine doesn't have the framework you thing it has. Check the setup log to see what actually happens

Comment: Well, if later framework version is installed I don't need previous one, do I?
When it requires to install framework 4.5 from component vendor's website I can't do it because of unavailable website(it forbidden in my company). But machine, as I said, has framework 4.5.2